# How to play smil file present in wowza content folder and its vod source files in s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, wowza, wowza-transcoder

I am creating smil file for live streams in wowza content folder. All my source files related to that stream is in s3 bucket. Now how to read that smil file and play video in different bit rates based on internet

Answer (score 0):

You can't, however you can use Wowza Media Cache, to retrieve data from S3. Take a look at Wowza website: [Playback from an Amazon S3 HTTP source](https://www.wowza.com/docs/how-to-scale-video-on-demand-streaming-with-media-cache#mediacacheconf_playbacks3)